# Best way to handle multiple connections at the same time

Tags: sockets, networking, vb6, window, connection

I have an application which listens to multiple connections and verifies whether the user is active or not

I use a 1 thread socket handling method with WSAASyncSelect.

The problem is that sometimes when a lot of users connecting at the same time some users get no reply

i think it is because the "send" hasn't been called yet and the program has received another connection so it goes again to handle the new connection ignoring the previous one. Like WSAASyncSelect has triggered and now it processing a new connection instead of completing the previous request.

So what to do to fix this issue? i tried to stop the events from WSAASyncSelect temporary by calling it with zero parameters when handling the connection until finish it then re enable network events but that didn't help either.

Here are the codes that handling the events (recieve then decrypt and then compare the bytes then send data according to what in listbox ie Active user or not)

**This called upon receive of FD_READ**

```
WSAAsyncSelect s, frmMain.hwnd, 0, 0 'Disabling Notifications event

Do Until bytesRecieved = SOCKET_ERROR
    bytesRecieved = recv(wParam, buffer(Bytes), 500, 0)
    If bytesRecieved > 0 Then
        Bytes = Bytes + bytesRecieved


    ElseIf bytesRecieved = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
Call MemCopy(ByVal decryptedArrival, buffer(0), Bytes)

WSAAsyncSelect s, frmMain.hwnd, WINSOCKMSG, FD_CONNECT + FD_READ + FD_CLOSE + FD_ACCEPT + FD_WRITE

If frmMain.chkSaveLog.value = vbChecked Then
    frmMain.txtConnectionsLog.Text = frmMain.txtConnectionsLog.Text & Now & " Receiving a connection (" & wParam & ")" & vbNewLine
    AutoScroll
    If frmMain.chkAutoSave.value = vbChecked Then
        strCurrentLogLine = Now & " Receiving a connection (" & wParam & ")"
        AutoSaveLog (strCurrentLogLine)
        frmMain.cmdClearLogs.Enabled = True
    End If
End If
```

Below here is a decryption of bytes then comparing by ID as byte identifier like 1 = check for update
2 - send user info etc

in a Select Case statement following by a send Api.

And the accepting procedure

This called upon receive of FD_ACCEPT

```
Function AcceptConnection(wParam As Long)

lpString = String(32, 0)


        AcSock = accept(wParam, sockaddress, Len(sockaddress))

        strTempIP = getascip(sockaddress.sin_addr)


        frmMain.txtConnectionsLog.Text = frmMain.txtConnectionsLog.Text & Now & " Getting a connection from IP address: " & _
        strTempIP & " (" & AcSock & ")" & vbNewLine
        AutoScroll
        If frmMain.chkAutoSave.value = vbChecked Then
         strCurrentLogLine = Now & " Getting a connection from IP address: " & strTempIP & " (" & AcSock & ")" & vbNewLine
          AutoSaveLog (strCurrentLogLine)
        End If

End Function
```

Are there any suggestions for a better performance?

Comment: Please show your actual code.  You are likely mishandling the events.

Comment: That kind of code is NOT the correct way to use `WSAAsyncSelect()`.

Comment: Then what is the correct way? where is my bug?

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Comment: why don't you use a (or more) winsock control(s) ?

Answer (score 2):

What you showed is NOT the correct way to use `WSAAsyncSelect()`.  Try something more like this instead:

When creating a listening socket:

```
lSock = socket(...)
bind(lSock, ...)
listen(lSock, ...)
WSAAsyncSelect lSock, frmMain.hwnd, WINSOCKMSG, FD_ACCEPT
```

When a listening socket receives `FD_ACCEPT`:

```
Function AcceptConnection(wParam As Long)

  AcSock = accept(wParam, sockaddress, Len(sockaddress))
  If AcSock = INVALID_SOCKET Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  WSAAsyncSelect AcSock, frmMain.hwnd, WINSOCKMSG, FD_READ + FD_CLOSE + FD_WRITE

  ...

End Function
```

When an accepted client socket receives `FD_READ`:

```
Function ReadConnection(wParam As Long)

  Do
    bytesRecieved = recv(wParam, ReadBuffer(ReadBytes), 500, 0)
    If bytesRecieved = SOCKET_ERROR Then
      If WSAGetLastError() <> WSAEWOULDBLOCK Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
    ElseIf bytesRecieved = 0 Then
      Exit Sub
    Else
      ReadBytes = ReadBytes + bytesRecieved
    End If
  Loop Until bytesRecieved = SOCKET_ERROR

  ' process ReadBuffer up to ReadBytes number of bytes as needed...
  ' remove processed bytes from front of ReadBuffer and decrement ReadBytes accordingly

  ...

End Function
```

When an accepted client socket receives `FD_WRITE`:

Function WriteConnection(wParam As Long)

While SendBytes > 0
    bytesSent = send(wParam, SendBuffer(0), SendBytes, 0)
    If bytesSent = SOCKET_ERROR Then
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ' remove bytesSent number of bytes from front of SendBuffer ...
    SendBytes = SendBytes - bytesSent;
  End While

End Function

The trick is that you need to allocate **separate** `ReadBuffer` and `SendBuffer` buffers for **each** accepted client.  Make sure that each time you receive `FD_READ` that you are appending bytes only to the `ReadBuffer` of the socket that triggered `FD_READ`, and each time you receive `FD_WRITE` that you are removing bytes only from the `SendBuffer` of the socket that triggered `FD_WRITE`.

When `recv()` has no more bytes to read, process that socket's `ReadBuffer` as needed, removing only complete messages from the front and leaving incomplete messages for later processing.

When `send()` fails with `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, append any unsent bytes to the `SendBuffer` of the socket that caused `send()` to fail.  When you receive an `FD_WRITE` event for a socket, check that socket's `SenBuffer` and resend any bytes that are in it, stopping when the `buffer` is exhausted or an `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, and quite effective, way to do it is to fork out for every incoming connection. This will most likely require you to restructure your application, but the basic flow should be as follows:
1. New connection is opened to the server
2. Server accepts the connection and forks out
3. The fork closes the original socket for listening, so only the parent will be accepting new connections
4. And then your magic happens, separate from the original thread.

This way you do not have to worry about issues of concurrency, as long as your machine can handle all the traffic and load because each connections is independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what do you mean by fork out? Sorry i am not English native speaker.

Comment: @amaninlove Fork is a system call that produces a carbon-copy of existing process: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)

Comment: Windows does not support forking, though.  This is a Windows system being targeted. The closest equivalent would be to spawn a separate thread/process for each accepted connection, leave the original socket to only accept connections and do nothing else. Let each thread/process handle its client independently of other threads/processes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if indeed windows is the target here (I didn't notice it anywhere in the post) then indeed threading will be the solution to choose. Problem with the threading approach is that it generally is more expensive than forking (in the model where we create a new thread for each accepted connection), and you will hit the upper limit much faster.

Comment: @Puciek: [`WSAASyncSelect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540.aspx) is a Windows-specific function. Threading can be done very efficiently if overlapped I/O or an I/O Completion Port is used for the socket I/O.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Quite possible, I've only done the testing on linux since it's the one platform with a choice :).

Comment: Problem is that VB6 is not thread safe! crashes upon TlsGetValue call inside msvbvm60.dll because it returns 0 if used CreateThread Api.

Comment: @amaninlove then you will have to work around the non-safe functions or move to another language, at least with the accepting connections part. For example you could use one of the tutorials for boost::asio to write a simple TCP server which will accept the connection, start a thread and within that thread launch your VB application (ugly but hey, I didn't pick VB ;)). You could make it a bit less funky by using messaging system